# modifying sql query to get different results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have  this query:

```
SELECT p.ProjectName,
       p.Oid AS Oid,
       p.[Views] as [Views],
       COUNT(pb.BidId) AS Bids
FROM Project p
LEFT OUTER JOIN ProjectContractorBid pb ON p.Oid = pb.ProjectID
WHERE p.Oid='A8704DA9-999B-4B13-806B-E8490C480F57'
GROUP BY p.ProjectName,
         p.Oid,
         p.[Views]
```

This is returning almost proper results:

[image: Screenoshot 1]

As you can see the bids column gets the number 3, those 3 bids are only for one of the projects but not for all of them the other projects doesn't have any bid at all.
I want to know what should I modify in the query to display 3 only for the project referenced in the p.Oid, not for each record returned in the query.

This is the project contractor bid table:

[image: Screenshot 2]

As you can see only angel test bid should have value of 3 not all the other results.
Please let me know what should I modify.
Thanks, Laziale

UPDATE: 
Project Table:

[image]

Comment: what does the `project` table look like? structure, data?

Comment: @bluefeet I included project table for that particular job poster, you can see all the projects posted. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to join on both the `ProjectName` and the `ProjectId`, otherwise the `Bids` value will be associated with all records in the project not just the records with the same `ProjectName`:

```
SELECT p.ProjectName, p.Oid as Oid, p.[Views] as [Views], pb.Bids
FROM Project p    
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  select count(*) Bids, ProjectID, ProjectName
  from ProjectContractorBid
  group by ProjectID, ProjectName
) pb 
  ON p.Oid = pb.ProjectID  
  AND p.ProjectName = pb.ProjectName
WHERE p.Oid='A8704DA9-999B-4B13-806B-E8490C480F57'
```

I also switched to use a subquery to get the count of the bids.

Answer (score 0):

Include ProjectName in the on condition.